# Which way is good to define font-family?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm working on project where I have to define font-family for the whole project and then I got a question in my mind that Which way is good to define **`font-family`** in my **stylesheet**?

**Like this**

```
*{
  font-family: sans-serif,Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
}
```

or

**Like this**

```
body{
      font-family: sans-serif,Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    }
```

Comment: avoid using the the * selector where ever possible

Comment: applying it to html or body tags is sufficient for the purposes of fonts as the cascade will take care of the rest.

Comment: Also, you put the less specific font (in this case `sans-serif) last in the list. Otherwise, it will be applied always, rather than as fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is better.

I would actually use:

```
html{
      font-family: sans-serif, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    }
```

Whether you use `html` or `body`, it does not really matter, but I have seen `html` more often

The universal selector (`*`) is extremely slow. It would be like finding every possible type of html tag and giving each of those the rule **seperately**

Comment: the universal selector is extremely slow. It would be like finding every possible type of html tag and giving each of those the rule **seperately**